# How can I search by remove ' - ' from my SKU?

Tags: magento2, search, sku, querystring

I have sku like this '1-83574148-0'.

when I searched  with keyword  '1835741480' . It's no result .

How can I search by remove  ' - ' from my SKU ?

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, after i did some analyses I found that the best approach for this  to add new attribute to product, this attribute should be searchable, then I saved the SKU without "-" to this attribute.

In this case you don not need to write any code and only you will use Magento standard.

Comment: Yes I knew this . but   I have more than 1m product sku .

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the below file where the search filter happens,

In **di.xml**,

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match"
                type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Search\QueryBuilder"/>
```

Model file,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Search;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Helper\Mysql\Fulltext;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\FieldInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\ScoreBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Query\BoolExpression;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\QueryInterface as RequestQueryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Preprocessor\PreprocessorInterface;

class QueryBuilder extends Match
{
    const SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = '-+~/\\<>\'":*$#@()!,.?`=%&^';

    const MINIMAL_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 3;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $replaceSymbols = [];

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var ResolverInterface
     */
    private $resolver;

    /**
     * @var Fulltext
     */
    private $fulltextHelper;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $fulltextSearchMode;

    /**
     * @var PreprocessorInterface[]
     */
    protected $preprocessors;

    /**
     * @param Http $request
     * @param ResolverInterface $resolver
     * @param Fulltext $fulltextHelper
     * @param string $fulltextSearchMode
     * @param PreprocessorInterface[] $preprocessors
     */
    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        ResolverInterface $resolver,
        Fulltext $fulltextHelper,
        $fulltextSearchMode = Fulltext::FULLTEXT_MODE_BOOLEAN,
        array $preprocessors = []
    ) {
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
        $this->replaceSymbols = str_split(self::SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, 1);
        $this->fulltextHelper = $fulltextHelper;
        $this->fulltextSearchMode = $fulltextSearchMode;
        $this->preprocessors = $preprocessors;
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($resolver,$fulltextHelper,$fulltextSearchMode,$preprocessors);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(
        ScoreBuilder $scoreBuilder,
        Select $select,
        RequestQueryInterface $query,
        $conditionType
    ) {

      /*  Code customization */

    }
}
```